# Change single itemtpl record on Sencha Touch List

Tags: sencha-touch-2

how can I change single itemtpl at itemtap event in Sencha Touch 2?
I would like to change HTML record's code when I click on item.
If I try to do this with setItemTpl() method on dataview it changes all list's records.
Thanks

Comment: How drastically does it have to change? You could just set certain parts of the HTML to hidden using CSS, and then show them when the `x-item-pressed` class is added to the is added to the row.

Answer (score 0):

On "itemtap" event, you can find the target from params. And then get the target element

```
var target = Ext.get(target);
```

then apply, `setHtml()` function there and do what you want.